# Specific Physics Lessons and Reference for Game Development

Tags: android, game-design, physics, game-mechanics

What "Physics stuffs" should I learn in game developments? I'm reading about Verlet Integration, and I'm wondering what other lesson should I learn and if there are available resources can you please provide some link or anything. Thanks.

Comment: The more specific you are in your question the better we can help you, although your question has 'specific' in the title it's quite broad :). So all I can say now is: take a look at existing physics engines and their design documents. I also found this which looks pretty cool: http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/

Comment: Thanks, link looks nice. Pardon me as I'm really new I have no idea what to call or name those terms.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very open question. Here are a few references I've found great for writing my always in progress engine :)

Online references:

- Indie Game Developer WildBunny has some great physics tutorials: [Link](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/tag/physics/) He focuses on Flash but his code is quite clean and easy to port to other languages.
- Chris Hecker has put online versions of his Game Developer articles (C++). It includes a few that are great. I like his style: [Link](http://www.chrishecker.com/Category%3aPhysics)

Books:

- [Physics for Game Developers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596000065) - This one was one of the first books that explained physics specifically for games. I find it's ok. I think the code is in C or C++.
- [Game Physics Engine Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123819768) - This one is great, very comprehensive but like all the books from this publishing company its big! It might be a little overkill even.

Comment: As open as the question is, great answer!